# Can program FPGA but not PROM on my Spartan-3A dev board

Tags: fpga, xilinx, ise

I decided to brush the dust off my Xilinx Spartan-3A starter board that I got a while back, and learn to use Verilog.  So with the help of Pong Chu's book [FPGA Prototyping By Verilog Examples: Xilinx Spartan-3 Version](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=fpga%20chu)
 I got a simple program written and compiled using the Xilinx ISE.

I then launched their IMPACT tool so I could download the program to the board.  After a few false starts, I was able to get everything configured (I thought) and download the program to the FPGA, and it ran.  But of course if I restarted the board, the demo program that came with the board was loaded off the PROM and started running again.

So I then tried to program the PROM instead.  Even thought the IMPACT console says the part is programmed (see below), when I restart the board I still get the original demo program running again.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got the wrong device.

[image]

In order to program the SPI Flash using the indirect JTAG method, you need to right click on the FPGA and select `Add BPI/SPI Flash`. It'll ask for the device type and your programming files. The type should be SPI Flash `M25P16` according to [this document](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug330.pdf), page 106. Then highlight the SPI Flash you just added and select the Program operation. When the Programming Properties comes up, Xilinx recommends you tick the `Verify` and `Erase before programming` options.

These instructions, and more, are available in the [Spartan-3A FPGA Starter Kit Board User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug330.pdf), the programming instructions for the indirect method start on page 103.

Note:

If the above doesn't work, check your Jumper settings. Taken from the User Guide. Page 103.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.  I didn't realize there were multiple ways I could program the configuration.  When switching the jumpers to the indirect SPI mode, I found one jumper that was probably set wrong for the Platform Flash PROM that I was trying to use, so I'm guessing that's why I couldn't program it. A little frustrating when the screen says Programming Successful when it wasn't.  But the SPI Flash works fine so I'll stay with that.